# Vertically centering icons and searchbox in a navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been struggling with how to do this reasonably - I need a navbar consisting of an icon on both sides and an expanding searchbox between them. As I achieve this, I can't use display: table-cell on the divs correctly and therefore can't vertically align them better than I have now (using paddings and margins with em's - not quite a viable option). Could anyone help?

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/65brxnb2/

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="formline">
    <div id="settingsicondiv"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="searchicondiv"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="searchboxdiv">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
.formline {
    max-width: 40em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.fa {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    margin-top: 0.15em;
}
#settingsicondiv {
    float:left;
}
#searchicondiv {
    float:right;
}
#searchboxdiv {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to set the `display` property of all your 3 `<div>`'s to `inline-block` and then align them vertically in the middle using `vertical-align: middle`. I also modified your HTML structure just a little bit by placing `<div id="searchboxdiv">` before `<div id="searchicondiv">`.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.fa {
  color: white;
}
#searchboxdiv {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#settingsicondiv,
#searchboxdiv,
#searchicondiv {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div#searchboxdiv {
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="formline">
    <div id="settingsicondiv"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-2x"></i>

    </div>
    <div id="searchboxdiv">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="searchicondiv"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this raises some new problems - now on very small widths the icons and the searchbox stack and I can't get the same result as before (input takes all space between icons and the whole div with the icons and the input will get a maximum width of 40em).

Comment: @user2257652 - You could place a `min-width` on `nav`. Something like `min-width: 200px;`

Comment: To fix that, you can set a smaller width for the search input over here: `div#searchboxdiv { width: 50%; }`. Moreover, I tried reducing my screensize all the way till 306px while testing the above snippet and all the three `<div>`'s remained in one line. Here's a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/65brxnb2/6/

Comment: @FahadHasan - this is not what I'm looking for. For example, on a 300px view I would need one icon to be on the right, one on the left and the input should take all the remaining space, not just a percentage - the space available on either left or right of the icons should only be there in case the viewport is wider than 40em (exactly as in my example JFiddle).